# How to fix access forbidden error in Windows XP IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis, iis-5

ASP .NET MVC2 application is installed in Windows XP , IIS 5.1 .

After opening several pages or pressing F5  file requests like

```
GET http://1.1.1.1:81/apps/Scripts/jquery.form.js HTTP/1.1
 Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
 Referer: http://1.1.1.1:81/app/Grid?_entity=Yksus6
```

return error

```
HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected
 Internet Information Services
```

Browser (IE9 ) should limit max number of concurrent connections to 3 . So Windows XP 10 connection limit should not occur here.
I tried in localhost also and same 403.9 exception occurs. Localhost should not have XP 10 connection limit.

Ideas to resolve:

Can disabling http 1.1 in iis fixes this so that HTTP 1.0 is used: 
I looked in IIS manager properties but havent found place where to disable 1.1
I Googled for "disable http 1.1 in iis" but havent found any information.
So I dont know how to disable http 1.1

XP supports also IIS 7 developemnt server. Should I try to install this ?

How to use asp .net mvc application in XP ?